# Is there an Android app that can comfortably reduce the resolution of built-in camera shots?

Tags: android, image-processing, camera

Current phones have a very high image size (in pixel dimensions).
However, when you zoom in to 100%, you'll probably find that the actual image resolution is poor there (little contrast between neighboring pixels).

In addition, current standard camera apps do not allow to pick a reduced megapixel dimension (like my old Huawei Android 8.0 phone did).

So to reduce the waste of storage capacity, I'd like to down-scale camera shots mostly automatically.

The problem does not only apply to still images, but also to videos:
For example when I record a few seconds of screencast to demonstrate some issue, the video is multiple MB, too large for an E-mail attachment in most cases.

Is there an app that can do that, or at least help doing that?
The standard tools seem unable to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I found ["imagepipe"](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/de.kaffeemitkoffein.imagepipe/) on [F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/).
It's not perfect, but it does the job.